# textSize and view width

Tags: android, textview

I'm having some issues handling the size of views with respect of the TextSize.
I have a textview which contains a six letter word and I would like to set the width of the view to match its content (I know I could simply set it to wrap_content, but I'm doing this as an exercise).
I set the width of the view as

view.setWidth(view.getTextSize()*6);

But I found that the view is slightly bigger than the text.
In particular, the size (in pixel) returned by the getTextSize() method appears to be bigger than the actual size of the font! (I'm using a monodroid font to avoid issues in the dimensions of the single letter).
Can anyone explain why this happens? Is there an error somewhere in my code or is this a known problem in android?

Comment: PS just to be clear, I cast the result of getTextSize() to int, but the difference between the float value and the casted int always results in a zero)